# Ruby - What are the differences between checking if block_given? and !block.nil?

Tags: ruby, performance, ruby-block

I have a ruby method that needs to check if a block was passed to it. 
A colleague is suggesting that simply checking if `block.nil?` is slightly faster in performance and works for named blocks. This is already quite annoying since he is using the named block and invoking it using `block.call` rather than `yield` which has been shown to be [significantly faster](http://mudge.name/2011/01/26/passing-blocks-in-ruby-without-block.html), since named blocks are more easy to understand in terms of readability.

Version 1:

```
def named_block &block
   if block.nil?
     puts "No block"
   else
     block.call
   end
end
```

Version 2:

```
def named_block &block
  if !block_given?
    puts "No block"
  else 
    block.call
  end
end
```

Benchmarking shows that version 1 is slightly faster than version 2, however a quick look at the [source code](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Kernel/block_given%3F) seems to suggest that `block_given?` is thread safe.

What are the main differences between the two approaches? Please help me prove him wrong!

Comment: What you are doing is called **“premature optimization.”** The productivity bottleneck _is never related to ruby internals_. So pick up any variant of your choice and go with it.

Comment: Also, `yield` might be perfectly used when named block is given instead of explicit `block.call`.

Comment: @mudasobwa It's still good to know the tradeoffs between implementations. Me & singletony work together on our company's infrastructure. We don't specifically care about the performance of each implementation but on the tradeoffs of each implementation.

Comment: @the_drow in Layman’s terms the answer is “there are no tradeoffs; pick up any approach and make sure it’s usage is consistent across the company.” `if !block_given?` negation under two-branched `if`, appeared in the OP, is waaaay worse, than `cb.nil?` vs `block_given?`.

Comment: @mudasobwa actually the invocation in our code is `block.call unless block.nil?` vs `block.call if block_given?`, so my post is a variation and I agree it wasn't the best one. That said, I agree with @the_drow, we care about the tradeoffs (and proving I am right) and some of the answers here address those well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, while a single `nil?` check might be faster than `block_given?`, capturing the block is slow. So unless you were going to capture it anyway, the performance argument is invalid.

Secondly, it's easier to understand. Whenever you see `block_given?`, you know exactly what is up. When you have `x.nil?`, you have to stop and think what `x` is.

Thirdly, it's an idiom. In my experience, the overwhelming majority of Ruby developers will prefer `block_given?`. When in Rome...

Lastly, you can keep it consistent. If you always use `block_given?` the problem is solved for you. If you use `nil?` checks, you have to have the block captured.

- There is a performance overhead.
- It's more verbose, something Rubyists try to avoid.
- Naming things is one of the hardest things in programming. :) Can you think of a good name for the block `Enumerable#map` will get for example?
- *"Grepability"* is a desirable trait for a codebase to have. If you want to find all the places where you check if you were given a block, doing `nil?` checks can prove difficult.

Comment: @the_drow what about reading ruby documentation on the subject? I voted for the question to be closed as “primarily opinion based,” and I suggest everybody here to do so.

Comment: @the_drow, procs are immutable. Also I haven't checked the implementation, but my guess is that a `nil?` check is atomic. So I don't think it makes a difference either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main difference is that `block_given?` can be used without explicitly defining `&block` in method definition:

```
def named_block
  if !block_given?
    puts "No block"
  else 
    yield
  end
end
```

Which version is better when it goes for readability? Sometimes explicitly naming the block can be more readable and sometimes `yield` can be more readable. It's also mater of personal preferences.

When it goes to speed, in benchmarks, that you've included, the `yield` is faster. That is because Ruby doesen't have to initialize new object (`Proc`) for the block and assign it to variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to accomplish this:

```
def named_block
   (Proc.new rescue puts("No block") || ->{}).call
end

▶ named_block
#⇒ No block
▶ named_block { puts 'BLOCK!' }
#⇒ BLOCK!
```

<sup>please don’t take this too seriously</sup>

**UPD**: as noted by @Lukas in comments, it fails on the block, that raises an exception ⇒ FIXED

Comment: To downvoters: I won’t remove this answer, I don’t care about reputation and this answer is **perfectly valid**. If for some reason you think it’s not a proper way to accomplish what’s asked, start with proving it.

Comment: I dont thing this is perfectly valid if i raise exception like this `named_block { raise ArgumentError, "Test error" }` your code produce 'No block' :)

Comment: @LukasBaliak indeed: added to answer. Anyway.

Comment: @LukasBaliak within your comment downvote would be fine, as a matter of fact :)

Comment: @LukasBaliak I fixed an issue, though :)

Comment: Nice, but i still prefere to use `block_given? ? block.() : 'No Block'` :D

Comment: I don't think it's a great answer--it's just too clever to be useful--but I did just learn what `Proc.new` does when not given a block.  Thanks for teaching me something.

Comment: Looks like this is deprecated now, Ruby 2.7.0p0 says `warning: Capturing the given block using Proc.new is deprecated; use '&block' instead`